# User agent reduction origin trialを利用したい

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

User-Agent Reduction origin trialは、公式ドキュメントによるとChromeのバージョン95から101までとなっていますが、トークン取得の画面を見ると、バージョン111まで有効のようです。私は現在バージョン109です。こちらは除外されているのでしょうか？
https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/user-agent-reduction-origin-trial/
https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/-7123568710593282047
公式ドキュメントを参考に、レスポンスヘッダに必要な設定を追加しましたが、正しく動作しません。
また、こちらはユーザーエージェント文字列やjavascriptのapiが完全に削除・変更された状況でのテストが目的です。完全に削除される前のテストを行うための他の方法はあるでしょうか？
ご教授いただけますと幸いです。